# Extrinsic parameters of camera - are they constant?

Tags: matrix, parameters, camera, rotation, calibration

I am wondering how can the extrinsic parameters of a camera be constant?
I know that the rotation matrix aligns the world coordinate system axises to the camera coordinate system, and the translation matrix/vector aligns the origo on top of each other.

But how can the parameters be constant? Would it not somehow be required that I know the orientation of the camera in world space? I.e. by an accelerometer or something?
I hope someone can help me wrap my head around this.

Comment: I believe we miss some background information here? The simple answer is that the extrinsic matrix is constant iff the world coordinate system is fixed and the camera is not being moved (no translation and no rotation).

Answer (score 3):

As you have correctly pointed out, camera extrinsics consist of a rotation and a translation of the camera's coordinate system relative to some world coordinate system. So, the extrinsics are constant only as long as the camera does not move relative to the world coordinates.  As soon as your camera moves, its extrinsics change.

When you calibrate your camera, you typically use multiple images of a planar calibration pattern. During the calibration process the extrinsics of each location of the calibration pattern are computed. Once the camera is calibrated, you can compute the extrinsics by detecting some reference points with known world coordinates in the image.  See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/measuring-planar-objects-with-a-calibrated-camera.html) in MATLAB.